# The new /review uses the word "votes" incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-declined, review

The big bold counter labeled "votes" shows the post's *score*, not the amount of votes that have been cast on that post. This is particularly confusing on the Close Vote tool, where such a counter would come in handy but is not available.

[image]

Incidentally, at least in this view, a "close votes" counter would actually come in handy.

Comment: Same on the questions tab on SO

Comment: If you want to see the close vote count, just click "Close" or visit the question's regular page. I like not having that number put in front of me until after I've made my decision.

Comment: @PopularDemand You still get it before you click 'Close' anyway

Answer (score 1):

"Votes" is the term we use consistently when shown with a post to the left.

Comment: What is "Score" then?  Is that the term used when referring to more than one post?

Comment: Wait, what? Just because something is done consistently means it's okay for it not to make sense...?

Comment: Why not just remove the word "votes" from that screen to avoid the confusion? We don't label it on regular posts, so why is it necessary to do so there?

Comment: I agree that even though it is consistent, it doesn't make a lot of sense. We always discuss the sum of up- and down-votes as "score". On a post that has +3 and -1, it doesn't make sense to say it has "2 votes" when in reality, 4 votes have been cast. We should fix that.